# Арифметическая операция с числами внутри одноимённых тегов xml?

Tags: xml

Есть большой xml документ, нужно взять все числа внутри одноимённых тегов, произвести с ними арифметическую операцию, вернуть их обратно, остальное не трогать.

То есть, например

```
<a> <b>100</b><b>200</b><b>300</b> </a>
```

все числа внутри тега b разделить на два.

Макросы notepad++ в арифметические не умеет, а js я боюсь как бы он остальной контент не попортил после преобразований в массив и обратно. Какие ещё есть варианты?

Comment: А что значит внутри одноименных? Какие условия на имя тега?

Comment: поправил: все числа внутри тега b разделить на два.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы не потерялось в комментариях, добавляю новым ответом.
С помощью xmlstarlet можно это сделать.
Для вашего файла

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a>
    <b>25</b>
    <b>300</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>255</b>
    <b>200</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>testing</b>
    <b>100</b>
  </a>
</root>
```

запуск из командной строки

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//b" -x ".div 2" my.xml >my_new.xml
```

Важный момент: для нечисловых значений в выводе получите "NaN" (посмотрите на тестовом примере)

Answer (score 2):

Собственно с помощью текстовых средств сделать это не представляется возможным. Ну есть совсем плохой вариант: хранить число и его половину и заменять одно на другое.

Предлагаю скрипт на Питоне

Входной файл (обратите внимание что правильный XML содержит корень):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a>
    <b>25</b>
    <b>300</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>255</b>
    <b>200</b>
  </a>
  <b>
    <b>testing</b>
    <b>100</b>
  </b>
</root>
```

Подключение библиотеки

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
```

Функция проверки на целое или вещественное число

```
def is_digit(string):
    if string.isdigit():
       return True
    else:
        try:
            float(string)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

Сам скрипт

```
fileName = "input.xml"
tree = ElementTree.parse(fileName)
root = tree.getroot()
for value in root.iter('b'):
       if is_digit(value.text):
            new_value = float(value.text) / 2
            value.text = str(new_value)
            value.set('updated', 'yes')

tree.write('output.xml')
```

Результат

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b updated="yes">12.5</b>
    <b updated="yes">150.0</b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b updated="yes">127.5</b>
    <b updated="yes">100.0</b>
  </a>
  <b>
    <b>testing</b>
    <b updated="yes">50.0</b>
  </b>
</root>
```

Если не нужно помечать обновленные теги, то уберите строку

```
value.set('updated', 'yes')
```